# In C# is there a better way to write this boolean evaluation

Tags: c#

this seems really awkward ...does anybody have any suggestions for a cleaner approach?

```
  bool case1 = (dte.StartDateTime >= Date) && (dte.StartDateTime < Date.AddHours(_interval));
  bool case2 = (dte.EndDateTime > Date) && (dte.EndDateTime < Date.AddHours(_interval));
  bool case3 = (dte.StartDateTime <= Date) && (dte.EndDateTime >= Date.AddHours(_interval));
  return ((dte.Association == Association) && (case1 | case2 | case3));
```

c#, .net 2.0

Comment: I actually like what you've done :).

Comment: That is poetry to my eyes and music to my ears.

Comment: You have lots of unnecessary parentheses..

Comment: I like descriptive variable names, even for booleans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

```
// this seems to rule out everything
if(dte.Association != Association) return false;
// find end
var endInterval = Date.AddHours(_interval);

return ((dte.StartDateTime >= Date) && (dte.StartDateTime < endInterval))
    || ((dte.EndDateTime > Date) && (dte.EndDateTime < endInterval))
    || ((dte.StartDateTime <= Date) && (dte.EndDateTime >= endInterval));
```

This is then short-circuited, and we only find the end date once.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to make your code more self-documenting by moving each of these boolean assignments into it's own method and then name the method for exactly what it is doing, as well as giving a descriptive name to your boolean value. But honestly, what you have there isn't bad

Comment: I'd say this would actually *increase* complexity, as I'd have to go searching for the definitions of additional methods. If this is just a single line of code that you're not using from anywhere else in the app, I say leave it as is.

Comment: To add self-documentation here all you need is rename the case1/case2/case3 with more descriptive names.

Answer (score 2):

Write a helper method, InRange which allows you to write:

```
bool case1 = DateTimeHelpers.InRange(dte.StartDate, Date, Date.AddHours(_interval));
```

Comment: I would also put `Date.AddHours` into the method and only pass the interval.

Comment: Yes, calling AddHours once must be better than calling it 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

You could write them like

```
return (
    dte.Association == Association
    && ((dte.StartDateTime >= Date && dte.StartDateTime < Date.AddHours(_interval))
     || (dte.EndDateTime > Date && dte.EndDateTime < Date.AddHours(_interval))
     || (dte.StartDateTime <= Date && dte.EndDateTime >= Date.AddHours(_interval))
    )
);
```

By the way - if I remember correctly - the `&&` operator is different from the `&`, the first one fails as soon as a condition fails and does not check the other conditions, while the second one evaluate them all, but I need to check this.

**Update**

Yep, it's that way, see [&& Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx).

Comment: That's correct. The `&&` operator **short-circuits**, meaning that it won't check the other conditions if the first one is sufficient to make the statement true. It's almost always the one you want to use for *logical* comparisons. The single `&` operator is for *bitwise* `AND` operators, and it does not short-circuit in logical expressions.

Comment: I am having a tough time reading this...are we missing some ORs

Comment: @Brad: You're right, I misread the ORs in the last row as ANDs. And sadly that worsens my solution. :\

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not better, but shorter:

```
DateTime end = Date.AddHours(_interval);

return dte.Association == Association 
  && (dte.StartDateTime >= Date && dte.StartDateTime < end
  || dte.EndDateTime > Date && dte.EndDateTime < end
  || dte.StartDateTime <= Date && dte.EndDateTime >= end);
```

Note that you should use `||` instead of `|` most times, since `||` is faster.

One thing which would be more important is that you comment this code, so somebody actually can understand what the code is effective ly doing..